# How to find one of many possible substrings in a larger string?

Tags: c#, split

I have a simple problem, but I could not find a simple solution yet.

I have a string containing for example this
`UNB+123UNH+234BGM+345DTM+456`
The actual string is lots larger, but you get the idea

now I have a set of values I need to find in this string
for example `UNH` and `BGM` and `DTM` and so on

So I need to search in the large string, and find the position of the first set of values.
something like this (not existing but to explain the idea)

```
string[] chars = {"UNH", "BGM", "DTM" };
int pos = test.IndexOfAny(chars);
```

in this case `pos` would be 8 because from all 3 substrings, `UNH` is the first occurrence in the variable `test`

What I actually trying to accomplish is splitting the large string into a list of strings, but the delimiter can be one of many values ("BGM", "UNH", "DTM")
So the result would be

```
UNB+123
UNH+234
BGM+345
DTM+456
```

I can off course build a loop that does `IndexOf` for each of the substrings, and then remember the smallest value, but that seems so inefficient. I am hoping for a better way to do this

EDIT
the substrings to search for are always 3 letters, but the text in between can be anything at all with any length

**EDIT**
It are always 3 alfanumeric characters, and then anything can be there, also lots of + signs

Comment: *"I can off course build a loop that does IndexOf for each of the substrings, and then remember the smallest value, but that seems so inefficient."* Did you benchmark this?

Comment: Is it always `[3 Letters]+[3 Numbers]` ?

Comment: Did you consider using a RegEx? Like @"(BGM|UNH|DTM).+?"

Comment: @Cid No, I did not. I thought I ask this here before I begin that. I am talking about 50 possible substrings, so that is a bit of work

Comment: @AustinG No, it does always start with 3 letters, but the text until the next separator can be anything at all

Comment: @KlausGütter I am not so good with RegEx. Could you help me on my way with this please ?

Comment: @TheGeneral It are always 3 alfanumeric characters, and then anything can be there, also lots of + sign

Comment: In my opinion, you should go with a loop + `input.IndexOf(arr[i]);`. That's easy to implement, easy to read, easy to maintain. Don't do [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: This is the good regex: (UNB|BGM|UNH|DTM)\+\d+ see: https://regex101.com/r/N6CuI0/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find more problems with EDI than just splitting into corresponding fields, what about conditions or multiple values or lists?. I recommend you to take a look at [EDI.net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net)

EDIT:
`EDIFact` is a format pretty complex to just use regex, as I mentioned before, you will have conditions for each format/field/process, you will need to catch the whole field in order to really parse it, means as example DTM can have one specific datetime format and in another EDI can have a `DateTime` format totally different.

However, this is the structure of a `DTM` field:

```
    DTM  DATE/TIME/PERIOD


       Function: To specify date, and/or time, or period.

010    C507 DATE/TIME/PERIOD                           M    1
       2005  Date or time or period function code
             qualifier                                 M      an..3
       2380  Date or time or period text               C      an..35
       2379  Date or time or period format code        C      an..3
```

So you will have always something like 'DTM+d3:d35:d3' to search for.

Really, it doesn't worth the struggle, use EDI.net, create your own POCO classes and work from there.

Friendly reminder that EDIFact changes every 6 months on Europe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will certainly read this. But I need this also for other purposes then just EDI

Comment: @GuidoG you should go into more detail about why an EDI to POCO parsing library doesn't meet your needs..

Comment: @CaiusJard I am definite going to read up on this library, I did not know it existed. But unfortunate I also need this for other purposes

Comment: nekeniehl, thank you so much for your remarks and the link. I installed the package and after some studying I am able to use this to read the EDI file. Much easier indeed.

Comment: Nekeniehl, you seem to have some knowledge about `Edi.net` Could you please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64533949/how-to-read-all-elements-with-the-same-header) question ?

Answer (score 2):

If the separators can be any one of UNB, UNH, BGM, or DTM, the following Regex could work:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(UNB|UNH|BGM|DTM).+?(?=(UNB|UNH|BGM|DTM)|$)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Explanation:

- (UNB|UNH|BGM|DTM) matches either of the separators
- .+? matches any string with at least one character (but as short as possible)
- (?=(UNB|UNH|BGM|DTM)|$) matches if either a separator follows or if the string ends there - the match is however not included in the value.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the other answer recognises the format - you should definitely consider a library specifically for parsing this format!

If you're intent on parsing it yourself, you could simply find the index of your identifiers in the string, determine the first 2 by position, and use those positions to `Substring` the original input

```
var input = "UNB+123UNH+234BGM+345DTM+456";
var chars = new[]{"UNH", "BGM", "DTM" };
var indexes = chars.Select(c => new{Length=c.Length,Position= input.IndexOf(c)})  // Get position and length of each input
                 .Where(x => x.Position>-1) // where there is actually a match
                 .OrderBy(x =>x.Position) // put them in order of the position in the input
                 .Take(2) // only interested in first 2
                 .ToArray(); // make it an array
if(indexes.Length < 2)
    throw new Exception("Did not find 2");   

var result = input.Substring(indexes[0].Position + indexes[0].Length, indexes[1].Position - indexes[0].Position - indexes[0].Length);
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tDiQLG

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly efficient *O(n)* solution using a `HashSet`

It's extremely simple, low allocations, more efficient than regex, and doesn't need a library

**Given**

```
private static HashSet<string> _set;

public static IEnumerable<string> Split(string input)
{
   var last = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < input.Length-3; i++)
   {
      if (!_set.Contains(input.Substring(i, 3))) continue;
      yield return input.Substring(last, i - last);
      last = i;
   }
   yield return input.Substring(last);
}
```

**Usage**

```
_set = new HashSet<string>(new []{ "UNH", "BGM", "DTM" });

var results = Split("UNB+123UNH+234BGM+345DTM+456");

foreach (var item in results)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
UNB+123
UNH+234
BGM+345
DTM+456
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QGiZzL)

<sub>***Note** : You could get this faster with a simple sorted tree, but would require more effort*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

There is already a lot of answers here, but I took the time to write mine so might as well post it even if it's not as elegant.

The code assumes all tags are accounted for in the `chars` array.

```cs
string str = "UNB+123UNH+234BGM+345DTM+456";
string[] chars = { "UNH", "BGM", "DTM" };
var locations = chars.Select(o => str.IndexOf(o)).Where(i => i > -1).OrderBy(o => o);
var resultList = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0;i < locations.Count();i++)
{
    var nextIndex = locations.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);
    nextIndex = nextIndex > 0 ? nextIndex : str.Length;
    nextIndex = nextIndex - locations.ElementAt(i);
    resultList.Add(str.Substring(locations.ElementAt(i), nextIndex));
}
```